# how to run community modules in awx

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I have the following module in my ansible playbook that I wish to run using awx:

```
- name: Clean up and Prune everything docker on oasis
      community.docker.docker_prune:
        containers: true
        images: true
        networks: true
        volumes: true
        builder_cache: true
```

When running this playbook I get the following error:

```
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.docker.docker_prune'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
The error appears to be in '/runner/project/update_machines.yml': line 38, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
    - name: Clean up and Prune everything docker on oasis
      ^ here
```

How do I fix it? I can run this using command line ansible with no issues on a different VM with ansible installed.

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 ways to do it.

1. Build your own environment executor with required modules included and
   use that. (you will need `ansible_build` for it). Look [here](https://medium.com/@frederic.egmorte/awx-create-a-new-execution-environment-with-ansible-builder-aee127d5bbdd) for more info
2. If your collections don't require system dependencies that may not be present in AWX EE, you can just put the requirements in `collections/requirements.yml` in your project folder. So I created a `collections` folder at the root of `ansible project directory` and then created a `requirements.yml` inside this folder. Add your required modules in this file. for example mine looks like this:

```
---
collections:
  - name: community.general
  - name: community.docker
```

More info [here](https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/userguide/projects.html#collections-support).